# Debian 8.10 without GUI streaming

Tags: debian, youtube

I have a server without a GUI. There is no possibility to get one because my server don't have a GPU and its a xeon processor. My question now is it posible to stream a 24/7 radio stream on youtube?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest MPV or mplayer + youtube-dl. Do "sudo apt install mpv youtube-dl" and then "mpv https://youtube.com/" but you might need X11, so install Xinit, and write this to .xinitrc, and then do startx. No desktop, just MPV.